# Getting kernel errors when manually mounting VirtualBox shared folders

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, shared-folders

Updated: I've rephrased this problem as I understand it a bit more now (and have encountered another problem).

I'm using a Fedora 15 guest on a Windows 7 host using VirtualBox. I am trying to mount a partition on the host PC as a shared folder for use in the guest.

The folder appears in `/media` and is accessible  when I use the auto-mount feature when setting up the shared folder, but when I attempt to mount without auto-mount I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mount.vboxsf data /mnt/host_data
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: Could not add an entry to the mount table.: Invalid argument
```

In addition a popup appears (part of Fedora/GNOME) reporting a crash in the kernel package:

> WARNING: at lib/list_debug.c:26 `__list_add+0x3e/0x81()`

However the shared folder seems to work, I can certainly browse it (although everything seems to be executable, probably down to a Windows host).

**Is there something wrong with what I'm doing or is this a bug (and in which case should it be reported to the Linux Kernel team or VirtualBox)?**

Comment: Could be a few things - have you tried re-installing the guest additions?

Comment: I have, and as far as I know they're for the right kernel. This setup did work initially on an Ubuntu guest.

Comment: Those with the same problem: for the time being I'm getting around this by using auto-mount and dealing with it living in /media; still confused as to why manual mounting does not work though.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the VirtualBox guest kernel driver or its userspace tools.  [You can report it here.](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker)